# How to run my php program through all posts?

Tags: wordpress

I made the following php program to set(over write) post tags by certain custom meta value.  Program itself works fine while I set it at header.php.

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
<?php
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;
$tags[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'aaaaa', true );
$tags[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bbbbb', true );
$tags[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ccccc', true );
$tags[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ddddd', true );  
$tags = array_unique( array_filter( $tags ) ); 
get_post_meta results
wp_set_post_tags($post_id , $tags, false );

?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now, I found that my program does not effect tags untill I open articles(posts) by browser.
I have many posts that I like to change tags by my program.  Is there way to run my program all through posts without opening by browser?

---

This is other code I tried.  I set this code on header.php like above code.  It works like above code.  I still need to open so many posts.  Is there way to run program through all posts in background?

```
<?php if (is_singular('post')): ?>
<?php
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;
$tags[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'aaaaa', true );
$tags[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bbbbb', true );
$tags[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ccccc', true );
$tags[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ddddd', true );  
$tags = array_unique( array_filter( $tags ) ); 
get_post_meta results
wp_set_post_tags($post_id , $tags, false );

?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this help you.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post'
);

$post_query = new WP_Query($args);
if($post_query->have_posts() ) {
    while($post_query->have_posts() ) {
        $post_query->the_post();

        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $tags[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'aaaaa', true );
        $tags[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bbbbb', true );
        $tags[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ccccc', true );
        $tags[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ddddd', true );  
        $tags = array_unique( array_filter( $tags ) ); 
        get_post_meta results
        wp_set_post_tags($post_id , $tags, false );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again.  what file I should set your code?  function.php?  I have so many pages to write over tags, and like to let program run through all posts like such plugin.  I need to open each page to run program while I set it at header.php.

Comment: Home page run one time

Comment: I could finally understand what you say in your answer.  Thanks a lot.  It helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (is_singular('post')) {

//your code here...

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I tried to set my code by your way on header.php , but I still need to open each post to run the program.

Comment: Please edit your answer and provide a brief description because StackOverflow puts answers without a brief explanation on the Low Quality posts review queue to see if they should be deleted...  The reason is thousands of people skim answers in a hurry to find the one that best solvers their problem and it wastes the time of a lot of people if they have to spend a lot of time studying answers to figure out if it's really the one they need, and have to read the question, reverse engineer your answer and possibly read language documentation to figure out what your fix solves or how it works.